# How to check that input value is correct in unit tests in Angular application?

Tags: angular

Here is my component and test of the component:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div>
      <input [(ngModel)]="kek" />
    </div>
  `
})
class MyComp {
  @Input() kek;
}

fdescribe('kek', () => {
  let component: MyComp;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComp>;
  let de: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComp],
      imports: [FormsModule]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComp);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    de = fixture.debugElement;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('', () => {
    component.kek = '228';

    expect(de.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement.value).toBe('');

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(de.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement.value).toBe('228');
  });
});
```

Test is not passing. Why? I expect that when I changed Input of component (`kek`), value of input is changed. Why value is `’’`?

Probably, I check the value of the input incorrectly. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

since you are binding kek with `[(ngModel)]` and his value is 228 after `component.kek = 228` you cant expect it to be ''.

Comment: Nope. It will be so until I call for `fixture.detectChanges();`. I added an answer and an example.

Answer (score 0):

An answer can be found there: [click](https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/unit-testing-of-simple-input-box-fdbba93f3d2e).

Also, you can use fakeAsync and tick helpers.

The problem is in that fact that ngModel has async nature. That's why you need to write an async test for that.

Example:

```
  it('', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.kek = '228';

    expect(de.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement.value).toBe('');

    fixture.detectChanges();

    tick();

    expect(de.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement.value).toBe('228');
  }));
```